# How spawn a program in Linux without locking current folder?

Tags: c++, linux, exec, truecrypt

On CentOS 6.3, In my main program I mount a Truecrypt volume containing executables A and B to a mount point, ./tmpfolder. I run program A, by doing

```
system("./tmpfolder/A")
```

from a forked child.

Program A does:
    if (fork() == 0){
      system("cp ./tmpfolder/B /tmp");
      chdir("/tmp");
      execl("/tmp/B", "B", (char *)0);
      exit(0);
    }

At this point program A exits, leaving program B running. So far so good.

Program B does:
    chdir ("/tmp");
    while(notdone){ /* do stuff */ }

Now I want to unmount the Truecrypt volume while leaving program B running. I cannot; the folder is in use.

After running A, `ps` shows B running, with PID 27643 (for example).
Then `ls -l /proc/27643/cwd` shows "/tmp". So the current working directory of B is not the mount point folder.

But my attempt to unmount fails: "device is busy".
And `fuser -c ~/tmpfolder` shows `27643`, the PID of program B.  So, somehow, program B is still using the mount point folder.

How can program B be still using the folder in which program A ran and then exited? How can I launch B without having it use the mount point folder?

Comment: Copying it (and changing current directory to) somewhere like /tmp should work. The reason the mount is locked is because the executable is `mmap`ed in, so the OS will need the file to stay open until the executable finishes. But if it's on a different path, it should be no problem.

Comment: It could as well be the current working directory. Go to /proc/<pid of B> and look where the cwd symlink is pointing to, in this case a simple chdir() might already solve that issue.